# Parenting a skeleton to an armature explodes most of the mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

When I parent a skeleton to an armature most of the skeleton mesh explodes forward. I have been working this model for a couple of weeks and this never happened before. The only difference it seems is that I am now using a slightly different t-pose with the palms facing down. Before the palms were lower and facing backwards and I never had a parenting problem with that. (palms facing down is better to position the ulna and radius).

Here's a video of the situation... https://youtu.be/arPxpkbGepg

the file is here... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M6xTU4pA77A5AaQroNllIBi5Rm0Rtd8x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The aramture is always have to be in Rest Pose, before you attach a mesh to it. Go to Pose Mode, select all the bones, and use Pose>>Apply>>Apply Pose As Rest Pose.

Comment: Thanks - I just tried that and I got an error because there are keyframes set. So, I deleted the keyframes and then Applied pose as rest pose but I then lose the position of the body mesh. See video for details... https://youtu.be/dqoWePm-QrA

Comment: I didn't know you have multiple meshes. In this case you have to apply the Aramature modifier on the ready mesh, then apply the rest pose, then parent it again with "Armature Deform".